# db2 jdbc: generate create table command

Tags: jdbc, db2, create-table

I'd like to generate a 'create table' command, i.e. a string which contains the create statement, with a pure jdbc connection. Is there a viable solution like the oracles DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL procedure?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not a tool that allows you to do that in DB2 with only SQL. The built-in modules do not include an option to retrieve a DDL.

However, what you can do is to create a external Java User-Defined Function that executes db2look, which is the tool to extract DDls in DB2.

Other way to do that is to access the DB2 catalog (dictionary) and recreate the DDL based on the metadata:

```
SELECT 'create table ' || t.tabname || ' ( ' || getColumns(t.tabname) || ')' || ..
FROM SYSCAT.TABLES t
;
```

And create functions to retrieves the columns, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my project http://code.google.com/p/db2-scheme2ddl/ for code samples.
I can get table DDL for IBM DB2 with pure JDBC.

In short,

1. Invoke undocumented DB2 function  CALL
   SYSPROC.DB2LK_GENERATE_DDL('-e -z SAMPLE', ?)
2. Store second INOUT
   parameter for later use
3. Find primary object's DDL with query

   select
       OP_SEQUENCE, SQL_STMT, OBJ_SCHEMA, OBJ_TYPE, OBJ_NAME, SQL_OPERATION
                               FROM SYSTOOLS.DB2LOOK_INFO where OP_TOKEN=? and OBJ_SCHEMA=? and OBJ_TYPE=? and OBJ_NAME=?